# How to set the height of the HTML page without considering the footer?

Tags: css, html

I want to leave out the footer of the height of the page such as Google Chrome does when you download a file. My page looks like this:

[image]

And I want to keep out of scrolling just like:

[image]

This is the code of my footer:

```
 <footer class="tr-emulate">
      <div class="float-left" style="margin-left: 5px; padding-top: 8px;">
          <button class="k-button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();">Cerrar sesión: @User.Identity.Name</button>
      </div>
      <div class="float-right" style="margin-right: 5px; padding-top: 12px;">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - DirecTV  &nbsp;</div>
 </footer>
```

and this is the CSS style of the tag:

```
footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 37px;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: it would be great if you could post your code so we can start from somewhere, and know what we are talking about. For example, is your footer in fixed position?

Comment: sorry, is that truth! Yes, my footer is in fixed position... i will edit my post in a moment! :)

Comment: it's done, what about now?

Comment: If i understood correctly you want the scrollbar to end above your footer and not next to it. Do achieve that you will need to define a new element like a `<div>` set it to `overflow:auto;` and set it's height to: clientHeight - footerHeight. Place all page contents aside from the footer inside this container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you on the right path:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwBh/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap{
    height:90%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#content{
    height:300%;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}

footer{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:red;
}
```